# How to change variable value in gradle depending on a flavor

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, artifactory

The issue that I have is, I have an android Library with two flavors A and B, each one have an independent Job in Jenkins to generate the artifact that will be published to Artifactory Repository.

In My build.gradle I configure the variable group to 'com.company.xx' which represents where I want to publish the artifact, but my problem is that I want to pusblish to a diferent group in each Flavor, so the question is how can I change that variable value depending on flavor I am building??

the group variable is outside all closures in the build.gradle like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply from: 'pom.gradle'

// Artifact configuration
group "com.company.xxx"
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried assigning a value to it in your flavor? This should work, that's how I'm doing it

```
productFlavors{
    flavorA{
        group "value1"
    }

    flavorB{
        group "value2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i added the variable and one of my jobs is working, but the other job that builds the second flavor is publishing to the same group as the first flavor, i am sure that the groups are different for each flavor, and in jenkins i added the assembleFlavorARelease task and for the other flavor assembleFlavorBRelease, is there anything else should i modify?